# Photo Gallery like facebook

Tags: jquery, photo-gallery

I have to create an image gallery like facebook. I am looking for a light box. When I click next image, the background needs to remain still and only the image needs to slide or change.

If you notice in fb photo gallery, it will reload the page but only the photo gallery will change, background posts will remain unchanged. how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are looking for [this](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/).

Comment: This doesn't reload the page . i need with reloading the page without changing the background content

Comment: what do you mean reload the page?

Comment: nothing is reloaded in fb in theather @RahulThiru

Comment: i see what you are saying

Comment: @RahulThiru how about this one http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto

Comment: most of them don't do what you want. it was hard to find one.

Comment: This way will reduce the page loding

Comment: I need another help . How to get auto_increment value of database table using sql without using the max(id) or previous id or row count

Comment: @RahulThiru http://stackoverflow.com/questions/813770/database-auto-increment-column

Comment: I found a way to do it simply . Just used iframe and changed src of iframe it did work as i needed.